# RestEasy - JSON response - From Angular2 client, how to only get JSON Object

Tags: json, angular, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm new to REST services, I have an Angular2 client calling a RestEasy JAX-RS service. All I am trying to get is a "Hello World" message in JSON format. I was expecting only a JSON object, but I get my response with the following structure:

```
_body: "{"message":"Hello World!!"}"
 headers: t
 ok: true
 status: 200
 statusText: "OK"
 type: 2
 url: "http://localhost:8080/helloapp/rest/hello/world"
 __proto__: ...
```

My question is, Is that the way it should be?

I mean, I thought I would be able to access the JSON object straight from the response. Something like

```
this.service.getHello()
.then( result => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(result)); //{message: "Hello World"}
  this.message = JSON.parse(result).message;
});
```

But I actually have to get it from *_body*:

```
   this.service.getHello()
    .then( result => {
      this.message = JSON.parse(result._body).message;
      console.log(this.message);//Hello World
    });
```

Is it a RestEasy configuration thing, is there a way to change that?

Or

Should I consider that I will always have a field *_body* in my response with my data, and that's the default response structure?

For eventual consideration, here is my backend code:

HelloWorld Service:

```
@Path("/hello")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {}

    @GET
    @Path("/world")
    public Message getHello(){
        return new Message("Hello World!!");    
    }
}
```

My RestEasy version is 3.1.1.Final running in Wildfly 10.1.0.Final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're getting back is the [`Response`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html) object from the `Http` request. This is what all `Http` operations will return. The easiest way to parse the JSON from that is to just call the `json()` method on it

```
this.service.getHello()
    .then((res: Response) => {
      let obj = res.json();
    });
```

If you want the `getHello` to just return the object without having to parse it (on the calling client), then you can do it inside the `getHello` method by mapping it (using the `Observable.map` operation)

```
getHello() {
  this.http.get(..)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just couldn't realise that as I'm using Angular HTTPModule, it is actually creating the response object. I am also using in my Service class 'rxjs/Rx'; library and converting it to a Promise instead of an Observable, like this: `return this.http.get( this.baseURL + 'hello/world').toPromise();` Just because that's how I learnt it. But using Observables is the right way?

Comment: I don't know about "right" way. It might just be a preference. But you will definitely be using Observable operators before turning into a promise (is that's what you choose)

Answer (score 1):

As peeskillet says above, you're getting back the entire Response from the request, and while sometimes you may want to examine the headers, perhaps to handle the different return conditions (retry or redirect on 4xx or 5xx responses for example), most of the time we assume a successful request and we just want the payload.

Angular2 encourages the use of Observables, so your service might look something like this:

```
getHello() 
{
return this.http.get(http://localhost:8080/helloapp/rest/hello/world)
}
```

And your component may look something like this:

```
data: string;

ngOnInit() {
 this.service
     .getHello()
     .map(response => response.json())
     .subscribe (
          data => {
                this.data = data, 
          },
          err => console.log('Error',err),
          () => console.log('data',this.data) 
     );
}
```

You call the service, which is an http.get() and returns an Observable object, and we use .map to parse the response as JSON, which also returns an Observable, which we subscribe to.

Subscribe has three callback functions, 
    .subscribe(**success**, **failure**, **complete**)

In the example above on **success** we assign the payload - data - to this.data, if the subscribe **fails**, you log the error, and when it **completes**, we can do whatever we like, but in this case, we log this.data to the console - that's optional, but I log out the results while developing and then strip them out later.